# VBA Applying code for multiple locations

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hello I have a macro that copies files from specific folders to a single folder and I am wondering whether the code I have can be altered to pull multiple files from multiple specified folders within one loop, as now I have to create a new module for every single folder path/file.

I have the following code:

```
Sub SmplAPP()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FrFldr As String
    Dim ToFldr As String
    Dim myVal1 As Variant
    Dim myValn As String

        myVal1 = InputBox("Please enter today's date in mm-dd format")
        myValn = Replace(myVal1, "-", "\")
        Range("I1").Value = myValn

        FrFldr = "\\xxxf003\sample_data\SAMPLE_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\SAMPLE_APPLICATION\2017\" & myValn
        ToFldr = "C:\Users\sample\Desktop\logs_to_upload"

            If Right(FrFldr, 1) = "\" Then
                FrFldr = Left(FrFldr, Len(FrFldr) - 1)
            End If

            If Right(ToFldr, 1) = "\" Then
                ToFldr = Left(ToFldr, Len(ToFldr) - 1)
            End If

        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

            If FSO.FolderExists(FrFldr) = False Then
                MsgBox FrFldr & " doesn't exist"
                Exit Sub
            End If

        FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FrFldr, Destination:=ToFldr

Call NextApp

    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want copy from different folder, you may use collection. I have amended your subroutine:

```
Sub SmplAPP()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim collFrFldr As New Collection
    Dim FrFldr As Variant
    Dim ToFldr As String
    Dim myVal1 As Variant
    Dim myValn As String

        myVal1 = InputBox("Please enter today's date in mm-dd format")
        myValn = Replace(myVal1, "-", "\")
        Range("I1").Value = myValn

        collFrFldr.Add "\\xxxf003\sample_data\SAMPLE_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\SAMPLE_APPLICATION\2017\" & myValn
        collFrFldr.Add "\\another folder"
        collFrFldr.Add "\\yet another folder"

        ToFldr = "c:\Users\u195567\test\"

        If Right(ToFldr, 1) = "\" Then
            ToFldr = Left(ToFldr, Len(ToFldr) - 1)
        End If

        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

        For Each FrFldr In collFrFldr
            If Right(FrFldr, 1) = "\" Then
                FrFldr = Left(FrFldr, Len(FrFldr) - 1)
            End If

            If FSO.FolderExists(FrFldr) = False Then
                MsgBox FrFldr & " doesn't exist"
                Exit Sub
            End If

        FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FrFldr, Destination:=ToFldr
        Next FrFldr

    Call NextApp

End Sub
```

Comment: So if I just add every folder I need to copy the files from I just put another line with `collFrFldr.Add "\\yet another folder"` every time right?

Comment: True. Of course, there are other possibilities too, you could use Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) to populate the collection or take strings from some range in the worksheet.

Comment: Your solution will do just fine for now, I can shorten the macro to two modules instead of 12 haha, thank you for the help!